# How to copy data column into another sheet according to match between column header and sheet name?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have an Excel tab ("ROW X") with a dataframe of 36 columns and 15 rows. I have 36 empty tabs, each labelled as one of the columns of the dataframe ("POT_1", "POT_2", etc).

I want to copy a column (say "POT_1") from the first worksheet and paste it in a precise position in the sheet whose name matches the column header).

I could find some code to paste manually a certain portion of the sheet into another one (see below), but with this method I'd have to type manually each of the 36 sheets names.

```vb
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Sheets("ROW 4").Range("B2:C2").Copy

Sheets("SP6_ST_5").Activate

Range("C9:C10").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: If the worksheet name is in the cell `A2` on the `ROW X` tab, then something like this: `wsName = Worksheets("ROW X").Range("A2").Value`, then `Worksheets(wsName)` to refer to the corresponding worksheet.

Comment: What column in the destination worksheet do you want to paste the copied column to? and is `POT_X` etc. the name format for the 36 worksheets? I ask this because in your code you use `SP6_ST_5`.

Comment: Does your table have headers, and those headers are the sheet names where the data should be copied?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

    Dim col as range
    For each col in activesheet.range("A1").Resize(15, 36).Columns
        col.copy activeworkbook.worksheets(col.cells(1).Value).Range("G5") 'for example
    Next col

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop through each cell in the header row in `Sheets("ROW X"), copy the column range and then paste the range to the correct worksheet using the cells' value as the name of the worksheet.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ROW X")
    For Each cel In .Range("A1:AJ1")
        .Range(.Cells(1, cel.Column), .Cells(.Rows.Count, cel.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Sheets(cel.Value).Range("A1")
    Next cel
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Column Ranges

- The main Sub is `copyColumn`, the 3rd Sub. The Subs behind are being
  called by it.
- The 1st Sub is an example how to use the main Sub for one worksheet,
  while the second is a more serious example to be used for all
  worksheets whose names are not contained in the `Exceptions` array.
- This will copy the values from an 'appropriate' column range in the Source Worksheet (`ROW_X`) starting from one cell below the header to the last cell containing data and paste it to the 'appropriate' Target Worksheet (`POT_1, POT_2 ...`) starting from the specified cell address (`TargetFirstCell`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub runCopyColumn()

    copyColumn ThisWorkbook, "ROW_X", "POT_1", "A2", True

End Sub

Sub runCopyColumnAll()
    
    Const SourceID As Variant = "ROW_X"
    Const TargetFirstCell As String = "A2"
    Dim Exceptions As Variant: Exceptions = Array("ROW_X") ' add more ...
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            copyColumn ThisWorkbook, SourceID, ws.Name, TargetFirstCell
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub

Sub copyColumn(Book As Workbook, _
               SourceID As Variant, _
               TargetID As Variant, _
               TargetFirstCellAddress As String, _
               Optional IncludeHeaders As Boolean = False)
    
    Const proc As String = "copyColumn"
    On Error GoTo cleanError
    
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = Book.Worksheets(SourceID)
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = Book.Worksheets(TargetID)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    defineHeaderCellRange rng, src, tgt.Name
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    getColumnRange Data, rng, IncludeHeaders
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Sub
    
    defineTargetFirstCell rng, tgt, TargetFirstCellAddress
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Write result to Target Range.
    rng.Resize(UBound(Data)).Value = Data

    Exit Sub

cleanError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description, _
           vbCritical, "Error in '" & proc & "'"

End Sub

Sub defineHeaderCellRange(ByRef HeaderCellRange As Range, _
                          Sheet As Worksheet, _
                          Header As String)
    
    Const proc As String = "defineHeaderCellRange"
    On Error GoTo cleanError
    
    Set HeaderCellRange = Sheet.Cells.Find( _
      Header, Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, Sheet.Columns.Count), _
      xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows)
    
    Exit Sub

cleanError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description, _
           vbCritical, "Error in '" & proc & "'"

End Sub

Sub getColumnRange(ByRef Data As Variant, _
                   HeaderCellRange As Range, _
                   Optional IncludeHeaders As Boolean = False)
    
    Const proc As String = "getColumnRange"
    On Error GoTo cleanError
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = HeaderCellRange.Worksheet.Columns(HeaderCellRange.Column) _
      .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If IncludeHeaders Then
        If rng.Row > HeaderCellRange.Row Then
            Data = HeaderCellRange.Worksheet.Range( _
                   HeaderCellRange, rng).Value
        Else
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
        End If
    Else
        If rng.Row = HeaderCellRange.Row Then Exit Sub
        If rng.Row > HeaderCellRange.Row + 1 Then
            Data = HeaderCellRange.Worksheet.Range( _
              HeaderCellRange.Offset(1), rng)
        Else
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
        End If
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

cleanError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description, _
           vbCritical, "Error in '" & proc & "'"

End Sub

Sub defineTargetFirstCell(ByRef rng As Range, _
                          Sheet As Worksheet, _
                          FirstCellAddress As String)
    
    Const proc As String = "defineTargetFirstCell"
    On Error GoTo cleanError
    
    Set rng = Sheet.Range(FirstCellAddress)
    ' Maybe you want to get rid of the previous data:
    'rng.Resize(Sheet.Rows.Count - rng.Row + 1).ClearContents ' or Clear ?
    
    Exit Sub

cleanError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description, _
           vbCritical, "Error in '" & proc & "'"

End Sub
```